# Why does attempting to connect to my ingress show connection refused?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, nginx-ingress

I'm running kubernetes 1-21-0 on Centos7. I've set up a keycloak service to test my ingress controller and am able to access the keycloak on the host url with the keycloak port like `myurl.com:30872`. These are my running services:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default         keycloak                             NodePort    10.96.11.164    <none>        8080:30872/TCP               21h
default         kubernetes                           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      11d
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.102.201.24   <none>        80:31110/TCP,443:30566/TCP   9m45s
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.107.90.207   <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP               9m45s
kube-system     kube-dns                             ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       11d
```

I've deployed the following [nginx ingress controller](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml).

And added an HTTP webhook to the service:

```
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service-webhook.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http-webhook
      port: 80
      targetPort: webhook
    - name: https-webhook
      port: 443
      targetPort: webhook
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

With this ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /keycloak
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: keycloak
              port: 
                number: 8080
```

Now when I attempt to connect to the keycloak service through the ingress I go to `myurl.com/keycloak` but it's unable to connect and trying to curl it from within my control node shows connection refused:

```
# curl -I http://127.0.0.1/keycloak
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:80; Connection refused
```

Can someone see what I'm missing?

**Edit:**

I realized the ingress controller actually works, but I need to specify its port also to reach it like this:

```
curl -I http://127.0.0.1:31110/keycloak
```

Which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: My first guess is that you are trying to reach the backend on port 8080 while the service is exposed on ports 80 and 443.

Comment: Thanks. That's they nginx controller service on ports 80 and 443, my keycloak service is on port 8080:

NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default         keycloak                             NodePort    10.96.11.164    <none>        8080:30872/TCP 

I realized the inrgess controller actually works, but I need to specifyi its port also to reach it like this:

curl -I http://127.0.0.1/31110/keycloak

Do you know how I can avoid needing to specify the port 31110?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to access the service outside the cluster when you have an ingress. Just keep the service on the port 80 for simplicity and map the ingress to that port of the service.
I don't get how why the curl is working since you are not specifying the port in this url: http://127.0.0.1/31110/keycloak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify `31110` port because your nginx ingress is set up with `NodePort` which means kubernetes listens to this port and all traffic that goes here is redirected to `nginx-ingress-controller` pod.

Depending on your setup and goals, this can be achieved differently.

**Option 1** - for testing purposes only and without any changes in setup. Works only on a control plane where `nginx-ingress-controller` pod is running

it's possible to forward traffic from outside port 80 to `nginx-ingress-controller` pod directly port 80. You can run this command (in background):

```
sudo kubectl port-forward ingress-nginx-controller-xxxxxxxx-yyyyy 80:80 -n ingress-nginx &
```

Curl test shows that it's working:

```
curl -I localhost/keycloak
Handling connection for 80
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 16 Jun 2021 13:19:23 GMT
```

Curl can be run on different instance, in this case command will look this way without specifying any ports:

```
curl -I public_ip/keycloak
```

**Option 2** - this one is a bit more difficult, however provides better results.

It's possible to expose pods outside of the cluster. Feature is called `hostPort` - it allows to expose a single container port on the host IP. To have this work on different worker nodes, `ingress-nginx-controller` should be deployed as `DaemonSet`.

Below parts in `values.yaml` for ingress-nginx helm chart that I corrected:

hostPort -> enabled -> **true**

```
  ## Use host ports 80 and 443
  ## Disabled by default
  ##
  hostPort:
    enabled: true
    ports:
      http: 80
      https: 443
```

kind -> **DaemonSet**

```
  ## DaemonSet or Deployment
  ##
  kind: DaemonSet
```

Then install ingress-nginx-controller from this chart.
What it does is by default `ingress-nginx-controller` pods will listen to traffic on 80 and 443 port.
Which confirms with simple test:

```
curl -I localhost/keycloak
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 16 Jun 2021 13:31:25 GMT
```

**Option 3** - may be considered as well if ingress-nginx is installed with LoadBalancer type.

Use `metallb` - software loadbalancer specifically designed for bare metal clusters. [How to install metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/#installation-by-manifest) and [configure](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/)

Once it's done and ingress-nginx is deployed, ingress-nginx will get External-IP:

kubectl get svc --all-namespaces

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.102.135.146   192.168.1.240   80:32400/TCP,443:32206/TCP   43s
```

Testing this again with `curl`:

```
curl -I 192.168.1.240/keycloak
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 16 Jun 2021 13:55:34 GMT
```

More information about topics above:

- [hostPorts and hostNetwork](https://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/)
- [Metallb project](https://metallb.universe.tf/)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get ahead.